# How to insert a pointer into an array list?

Tags: c

the ??? is where code needs to be added, I don't really know the correct syntax for inserting a pointer into an arraylist

```
ArrayList *playerList = ArrayList_create(sizeof(Player)); //notice, pass in sizeof(gameBoard)
char playerName[20];
Player *newPlayer;
printf("Enter Player 1 name: \n");
fgets(playerName, 10, stdin);
playerName[strlen(playerName) - 1] = '\0'; // Remove trailing newline
//put player into player Arraylist
????
//remember to do this

srand(time(NULL));
p1 = ????;  //<----now just get player number 1

while(true){p
  //now play the game
  int spin = randomNumber(3)+1;
```

Comment: 'ArrayList' is not a thing in C.  You'll have to consult your library that defines it.

Comment: Is the `sizeof(Player)` argument to `ArrayList_create` the size of each element it will store? Then you create the list to store `Player` *objects* (structure instances) not pointers to it.